моя игра очень лагает , когда я её запускаю. Когда я прыгаю она вообще иногда зависает на 5-10 секунд
import pygame

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
runned = True
color_bg = 0
pygame.display.set_caption('My Game')
icon = pygame.image.load('png/icon.png')
bg = pygame.image.load('png/bg.jpg')

pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#Переменные

player_BIG = pygame.image.load('png/right/1.png')
player = pygame.transform.rotozoom(player_BIG, 0, 0.5)



right_2 = pygame.image.load('png/right/2.png')
right_3 = pygame.image.load('png/right/3.png')
right_4 = pygame.image.load('png/right/4.png')

right_2_SMALL = pygame.transform.rotozoom(right_2, 0, 0.5)
right_3_SMALL = pygame.transform.rotozoom(right_3, 0, 0.5)
right_4_SMALL = pygame.transform.rotozoom(right_4, 0, 0.5)

left_2 = pygame.image.load('png/left/2.png')
left_3 = pygame.image.load('png/left/3.png')
left_4 = pygame.image.load('png/left/4.png')

left_2_SMALL = pygame.transform.rotozoom(left_2, 0, 0.5)
left_3_SMALL = pygame.transform.rotozoom(left_3, 0, 0.5)
left_4_SMALL = pygame.transform.rotozoom(left_4, 0, 0.5)


player_cord = [250, 475]

player_anim_count = 1

key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

is_jump = False
jump_count = 7

#Функции

def MoveRight():
    global player_anim_count
    global player_cord
    global player


    player_cord[0] += 19

    if player_anim_count == 4:
        player_anim_count = 1
    else:
        player_anim_count += 1

    if player_anim_count == 2:
        player = right_2_SMALL
    elif player_anim_count == 3:
        player = right_3_SMALL
    elif player_anim_count == 4:
        player = right_4_SMALL


def MoveLeft():
    global player_anim_count
    global player_cord
    global player


    if player_anim_count == 4:
        player_anim_count = 1
    else:
        player_anim_count += 1

    if player_anim_count == 2:
        player = left_2_SMALL
    elif player_anim_count == 3:
        player = left_3_SMALL
    elif player_anim_count == 4:
        player = left_4_SMALL

    player_cord[0] -= 19


while runned:




    window.blit(bg, (0,0))




    window.blit(player, (player_cord))





    pygame.display.update()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runned = False
            pygame.quit()

        if not is_jump:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                is_jump = True
        else:
            if jump_count >= -7:
                if jump_count >0:
                    player_cord[1] -= (jump_count ** 2) / 2
                else:
                    player_cord[1] += (jump_count ** 2) / 2
                jump_count -= 1

            else:
                is_jump = False
                jump_count = 7

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            MoveRight()

        elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
            MoveLeft()


    clock.tick(20) 


Переведи на русский язык, добавь пояснений

моя игра очень лагает , когда я её запускаю. Когда я прыгаю она вообще иногда зависает на 5-10 секунд

Не знаю, конечно, тут есть к чему придраться, в примерах немного по-другому всё делают https://riptutorial.com/pygame но в целом вроде бы не должно быть никаких фризов. А фоновая картинка bg.jpg не слишком большая? Попробуйте может 60 FPS поставить clock.tick(60), хотя вряд ли это поможет.

Запустил у себя — не лагает. Но принципиальная проблема в том, что перемещение player'а зачем-то выполняется только при наличии событий. Если событий нет, то цикл for event in pygame.event.get(): не запускается и соответственно ничего не перемещается. Я вынес весь связанный с перемещением код за пределы цикла — и стало гораздо приятнее (хотя 20 фпс это всё ещё не очень приятно, но это уже совсем другая история)

@andreymal Кстати, да. Падение то в прыжке после отпускания пробела должно как-то отрабатываться, а тут получается только один такт при отпускании пробела отработает и всё, событий больше не будет. Наверное из-за этого все проблемы.

прыжок работает только тогда, когда ты зажимаешь пробел, если просто жмёшь , он зависает в воздухе и всё

@andreymal скинь исправленный код

@Dogrog ну выделить кусок кода и нажать Shift+Tab вы и сами можете
